# How to find the minimum value of algebraic expression on specific interval?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How I can solve the following problem:
$$4x-x^2\in{\mathbb Z},$$$$ -2<x\leq 4 \Rightarrow \min(4x-x^2)=?$$

Comment: Do you know how to find the min/max of a smooth function, in general?

Comment: Yes I know, but I think this problem can't solved directly using derivatives. Can you provide me with your method please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, such problems require the use of a derivative to find the points where the function achieves local minima and maxima, but this case is simpler and can be done without it.

Note that $$ f(x) = 4x-x^2 = 4- (x-2)^2$$
by sketching the graph (a parabola with the vertex at $(2,4)$, arms oriented downwards) you can see that the function is increasing for $x\in(-\infty,2]$ and decreasing for $x\in [2,\infty)$. That means that when you take the interval $[-2,4]$, the function will have the minimal value at one of its end points.

You have $f(-2)=-12< 0=f(4)$ so $$ \min_{-2\le x \le 4} f(x) = f(-2) = -12$$

There's one more note. if you exclude the point $x=-2$ the function dosn't have a minimum on the interval $(-2,4]$. It can take valeues arbitrarily close to $-12$ but it never takes value $-12$. In this case, $-12$ is the *infimum* of the set of the values of the function, not the minimum.
$$ \min_{-2< x \le 4} f(x) \text{ doesn't exist}$$
$$ \inf_{-2 < x \le 4} f(x) = -12$$
If you search for the minimum integer value of the function, then since $-12$ isn't actually ever achieved, then it will be $-11$:
$$\min \{f(x): (-2<x\le 4)\land(f(x)\in\mathbb Z)\} = -11 $$

Comment: Perfect, I think they put the condition $4x-x^2\in{z}$ for this reason, so the minimum should be -11.

Comment: @Husam Yeah, I've just added that part to the answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have just see it.

Comment: Another thing, do you think we can find this minimum by using inequalities properties only?

Comment: @Husam It's possible, but it's difficult to guess the method without knowing the answer first. You have $$ 4x-x^2 = -12 + (x+2) (6-x)$$
For $x\in(-2,4]$, the second term is positive, so you have $4x-x^2 > -12 $, with the equality being approached when $x\rightarrow -2$.

Answer (score 1):

We *complete the square*, to get $4x-x^2=-(x^2-4x+4-4)=-(x-2)^2+4$.

This is a parabola opening downward.

It has its minimum at $x=-2$.  We get $-((-2-2)^2-4)=-12$.

Since you've excluded $x=-2$, the minimum integer is $-11$.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not familiar with calculus here is a graphical approach.

[image]

Plot $4x-x^2$. It is parabola. At $x=-2$ value is $-12$.

However $x\neq -2$.

[image]

When $x  = -1$  value is $-5$. At $x=0,2 \& 4$ the values are $0,4 \& 0$ respectively.

Other answers have shown how to complete square and find minimum.